# PHP, Bootstrap - Change span label based on range of numbers

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I am showing statistics from my database, if the number is between 80 and 99 I want the label to be label-success, if the number is between 51 and 79 label-warning and if the number is between 0 and 50 label-danger.

Something like this:

```
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM stats");
    foreach ($query as $row) {

                $points = $row['points'];
            $votes = $row['votes'];


$postclass = "";

foreach (range(0,50) as $row) {
    $posclass = "danger";
}

foreach (range(51,79) as $row) {
    $posclass = "warning";
}

foreach (range(80,99) as $row) {
    $posclass = "success";
}


echo '
<span class="label label-'.$posclass.'" >'.$points.'</span>
<span class="label label-'.$posclass.'" >'.$votes.'</span>
';

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work, I'm asking how to do it.

Comment: What number are you trying to compare? $row is an array. The id? The rows total?

Comment: well the problem is in the odd lines foreach (range(0, 50) as $row but there was no question in your question. I'm assuming you want if ($points >= 0 && $points <= 50) { $postclass = "danger" }

Comment: If $votes or $points is in one of the ranges, change the label accordingly.

Comment: There are many things wrong with the code you just posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is busted an bizarre, you are looping over a range of numbers and assigning the number to $row... If I'm understanding your desire, I think you need to change your code to look like this, specifically on each row to see if the $points value is within a particular range.

Last update adds a seperatelabel for Points and Votes

```
$postclass = "";
if ($points > 0 && $points <= 50) {
    $pointsLabel = "danger";
} else if ($points > 50 && $points <= 79) {
    $pointsLabel = "warning";
} else {
    $pointsLabel = "success";
}

if ($votes > 0 && $votes<= 50) {
    $votesLabel = "danger";
} else if ($votes> 50 && $votes<= 79) {
    $votesLabel = "warning";
} else {
    $votesLabel = "success";
}

echo '
<span class="label label-'.$pointsLabel.'" >'.$points.'</span>
<span class="label label-'.$votesLabel.'" >'.$votes.'</span>
';
```

Comment: The comment says, "if $votes or $points are in one of the ranges," so you should add checks for $votes as well.  Also, I would default to "danger," not "success," just in case.

Comment: This is what I want but there is multiple variables like $points and $votes that I haven't shownand by multiple I mean 20-30 variables, Should I do it like this for each one?

Comment: @user1626410 Yes but I just edited it to use a label for both points and votes